# Inconsistency between API data and homepage

Tags: support, api

When using the `/info` page on the API, the total_questions value is higher than the amount of questions on the homepage. For example, Programming Puzzles and Code Golf's /info page is:

```
{"items":[{"new_active_users":2,"total_users":25163,"badges_per_minute":0.02,"total_badges":47327,"total_votes":185526,"total_comments":81000,"answers_per_minute":0.01,"questions_per_minute":0,"total_answers":26484,"total_accepted":1670,"total_unanswered":45,"total_questions":2785,"api_revision":"2014.12.11.13645"}],"has_more":false,"quota_max":300,"quota_remaining":296}
```

And it says the total questions amount is 2785. But the homepage says it's 2772 questions:

[image: Code Golf questions]

Is this a bug, or is this by design and are there some questions included in the API which are not included on the homepage?

Comment: Removed questions? may be. Just a thought.

Comment: @MagicalPhoenixϡ That was my initial thought too, but for Meta Programming Puzzles & Code Golf, the API returns the same number as the homepage, and there certainly deleted questions on Meta PPCG.

Comment: Have you tried a hard refresh to rule out browser caching?

Comment: @SamB. Hard-refreshing didn't change something.

Comment: @ProgramFOX interesting, curious to see the answer.

Comment: I'd almost bet sever-side caching.  There are elements on the front page that are heavily cached for performance reasons.  The number of questions, since it is not a critical number for users, probably does not get updated often.